# What css cursor size is supported on various platforms/browsers?

Tags: css

Firefox says they support 128px cursors, but that you must keep within 32x32px for support "on all platforms". Does anyone know what platforms/broswers support what size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be an operating system limitation as opposed to a browser limitation. According to the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#cursor-props):

> Intrinsic sizes for cursors are calculated as for background images, except
>   that a UA-defined rectangle is used in place of the rectangle that establishes
>   the coordinate system for the 'background-image' property. This UA-defined
>   rectangle should be based on the size of a typical cursor on the UA's
>   operating system. If the resulting cursor size does not fit within
>   this rectangle, the UA may proportionally scale the resulting cursor
>   down until it fits within the rectangle.

An alternative would be to hide the cursor and use JavaScript to create a div with a background image that follows wherever the cursor goes, if you are in need to use larger cursors.

Comment: Or it may be both. It's entirely up to the UA what it wants to do with the cursor image.